# opposite of no_overlap constraint in docplex for CP

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, docplex, job-shop-scheduling

I am using python for CP solving.
I would like to know if there is constraint that does the opposite of no_overlap.
This will be like
overlap(*interval, arr, n*)

*interval* - single interval variable

*arr* - array of interval variables

*n* - positive integer less than length of *arr*

this will mean that atleast *n* interval variables from *arr* overlap in the interval of *interval*

This is for a situation in job scheduling when a job is not possible to be scheduled on a machine because there are already *n* higher priority jobs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [overlap_length](https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/docplex.cp.modeler.py.html?highlight=overlap_length#docplex.cp.modeler.overlap_length)

```
docplex.cp.modeler.overlap_length(interval, interval2, absentValue=None)

    Returns the length of the overlap of two interval variables.
```

and [count true constraints](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocounttrueconstraints.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# Data

Buses=[
    (40,500),
    (30,400),
    (35,450),
    (20,300)
    ]

nbKids=300

# Indexes

busSize=0;
busCost=1;

for b in Buses:
    print("buses with ",b[busSize]," seats cost ",b[busCost])

print()    

mdl = Model(name='buses')

#decision variables
mdl.nbBus=mdl.integer_var_dict(Buses,name="nbBus")

# Constraint
mdl.add_constraint(mdl.sum(mdl.nbBus[b]*b[busSize] for b in Buses) >= nbKids, 'kids')

# Objective
mdl.minimize(sum(mdl.nbBus[b]*b[busCost] for b in Buses))

mdl.solve()

# Display solution
for b in Buses:
    print(mdl.nbBus[b].solution_value," buses with ",b[busSize]," seats");

#Add a constraint
# Number of sizes where we have 1 or 2 buses should be at least 3

mdl.add(mdl.sum(mdl.logical_and(1<=mdl.nbBus[b],mdl.nbBus[b]<=2) for b in Buses) >=3)

mdl.solve()

print()
print("Number of sizes where we have 1 or 2 buses should be at least 3")
print()

# Display solution
for b in Buses:
    print(mdl.nbBus[b].solution_value," buses with ",b[busSize]," seats");
```

in OPL I would write

```
using CP;

int N=4;
int n=2;
dvar interval itvs;
dvar interval arr[1..N];

subject to
{
  (sum(i in 1..N) (1<=overlapLength(itvs,arr[i])))>=n;
}
```

and the same can be done with all APIs

Comment: The overlap constraint only overlaps 2 interval variables at a time.
However I want that atleast n intervals overlap with it for its entire duration. NOTE here that the overlapping task can end in the interval of the first variable and new task can start. However all such interval variables would be in the input array.

I am trying to model it using the idea in the second part.

Comment: That is why you need count true constraints to check how many overlap

Comment: But this is difficult with interval variables and not as staright forward.